# Scala Play 2.8 Framework: Splitting the route file, prefix contains a dynamic part

Tags: scala, playframework

I am having trouble [spritting](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/sbtSubProjects#Splitting-the-route-file) the `routes` file, as a `prefix` contains a dynamic part.
Can I do smth about it?

routes:

```scala
->  /admin/:hash/v1 admin.Routes
```

admin.routes

```scala
GET /users controller.ManageUsers(hash: String)
```

Autogenerated code looks like:

```scala
private[this] val prefixed_admin_Routes_0_416 = Include(admin_Routes_0.withPrefix(this.prefix + (if (this.prefix.endsWith("/")) "" else "/") + "admin/$hash<[^/]+>/v1"))
```

I am ok to even drop that `:hash` part, without propagating to the controller, but it's a dynamic part in the url.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of solved it with not having a prefix in the main route:

routes:

```scala
->  / admin.Routes
```

admin.routes

```
GET /admin/:hash/v1/users controller.ManageUsers(hash: String)
```